# Phalcon Volt gets really slow after chaining different models

Tags: performance, model, phalcon, volt

For some reporting issues I have to use codes as

```
{{ Model1.Model2.Model3.name }}
```

in for loops. I know it is not the best way (or may be the worst) to use but things happened and now I have to figure out some way to make this load faster. Because although there are 300 rows it takes nearly 10 secs to load.

My question is, how can I cache some of these results which are not actually queries on the backend? Or would you suggest an other way to make page loading faster?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a different strategy to get the model meta data ? I mean, if you didn't setup anything on your config file, everytime you make a query, Phalcon must query the database first to know the "metadata" of the table(Columns, column type, nullable, etc).

You can change your strategy to annotation, or at least cache the table metadata.

Please check Phalcon [documentation](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models-metadata.html)